# reading and writing expressions from file for java

Tags: java, file-io, stack, expression

Hello first time user here not sure if I am doing this right but here goes nothing.

I am trying compute math expressions such as 3*(2+7)-9 or 11/5*(3+3) by reading it from file and then writing the answer back to the file. I am not sure on how to read the entire expression as I have only done like simple things like read 3 strings and go onto the next time from file. and the idea is to use the expression read from files and compute them using stacks in java. I got how to compute it without reading from file but not really sure how to combine it all together into a single working programs, any ideas or tips?

Comment: Can you show some code of what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you think or know the math expressions will be written in the text file. If this is a file with only expressions that are separated by some character, then you can use something like this:

```
    ArrayList<String> expressions = new ArrayList<String>();
    try (Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"))) {
        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            String fullLine = s.nextLine();
            String[] expArray = fullLine.split(",");
            for (String exp : expArray) {
                expressions.add(exp);
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

You don't have to pack it into an arraylist if you do not want. You can calculate it and print it right to a file. But this will take each full line of the file and split it into pieces of string between each comma.

I'm just assuming a comma in this case. If the expressions are separated by a space, you can bypass the `.split()` and just use `s.next()` instead of `s.nextLine()`.

You could also use Scanner's `useDelimiter()` function. Set the delimiter to whatever is separating the expressions, and then when you use `s.next()` it will give you the tokens between the delimiters.

You'll also have to do a bit more to actually parse the expression as it is currently stored as a string. That should not be too difficult.